# unable to click on paper button using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to identify the element but unfortunately i was not able to click on the button because i am getting null pointer exception

```
<pre>
<paper-button class="include-btn" id="include-btn0" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" elevation="0" aria-disabled="false">
                                        Include
                                    </paper-button>
</pre>
```

and exception  am getting is

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   automation.carousel.allRules.positiveScenarios.TestCarouselAllRules.CreateRule(TestCarouselAllRules.java:239)
>     at
>   automation.carousel.allRules.positiveScenarios.TestCarouselAllRules.launch(TestCarouselAllRules.java:214)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: Add more description to your quesiton. Paste your code. Also go through the link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you share your code at this line : `automation.carousel.allRules.positiveScenarios.TestCarouselAllRules.CreateRule(TestCarouselAllRules.java:239)`

Comment: `NullPointerException` won't be raised while `identifying the element` but somewhere else. Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of getting NullPointer may be that when you are trying to get WebElement it is giving null and then you are trying to click on element that is null.
Try below code:

```
List<WebElement> includeButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//paper-button[@class='include-btn']"));
        if (includeButton.size() > 0) {
            includeButton.get(0).click();
        }
```